# Can I put a water sensor in the ceiling?

Tags: water-damage, home-automation

I live in an apartment. My upstairs neighbour's bath drain leaked into my ceiling. It was a slow leak from a corrosion hole, so it took a long time to visibly show up. We had to replace the ceiling when it finally showed up as a bubble in the paint.

Can I leave some sort of sensor in the ceiling to alert me before this happens again or if the repair fails?

I found some "leak" detectors online, but they seem to go on the water supply and alert if there's constant flow. From what I can tell, this won't work.

I envision something like a [humidity sensor](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Sensirion/SEK-SHT40-AD1F-Sensors?qs=rQFj71Wb1eVw4oE%2F4qSRuQ%3D%3D) or similar and running the cable out of the ceiling for power and data. Obviously it would need some care and feeding -- I'd need to run it without the alarm for a while to know what levels are "ok", somewhere for the data to go to, etc.

Let me know if anyone's tried this, if I'm obviously barking up the wrong tree, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A water leak will not necessarily increase humidity.  There are many devices on the market such as

**Phyn Smart Water Sensor** Its stand alone and has temperature and humidity alerts[image]

**Eve Water Guard** You stick the sensor at the end of the cable where you need it.[image]

**D-Link DCH-S161 Wi-Fi Water Sensor** Detects moisture (not humidity)
[image]

---

I am not associated with any of them.  Find a supplier near you using terms such as water sensor, flood sensor.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote